# Angular directive attribute does not bind with the controller

Tags: angularjs

I have a directive called orders-list and i need to bind the object currentOrder inside the controller with object inside the loop that was clicked on;

```
//controler
app.controller("receivedOrders", ['$scope', 'orders', 'Order', 'currentOrder', function ($scope, orders, Order, currentOrder) {
  $scope.currentOrder = null;
  $scope.orders = orders['content'];


//directive
app.directive("ordersList", function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'templates/orders_list.html',
    scope: {orders: '=', currentOrder: '='},
    controller: ['$scope','$attrs', function ($scope, $attrs) {
        $scope.selectOrder =function(order){
            $attrs.currentOrder=order;
        };
     //some other functions
    }]
}

//directive definition
<orders-list current-order="currentOrder" orders="orders"></orders-list>

//directive body
<md-list>
    <order ng-repeat="order in orders|filter:query|orderBy:activeSorting.directionSign+activeSorting.name"
           order="order" ng-click="selectOrder(order)"></order>
</md-list>
```

-------- Changes---------

So ok now i pass the function selectOrder to the inner directive order, and invoke the selectOrder function from it`s scope, but it still does not work =(

```
app.directive('order', function () {
return {
    restrict: "E",
    templateUrl: '/templates/order.html',
    scope: {
        order: '=',
        orderClick:'&'
    },

<md-list-item order-click="orderClick({order:order})" class="md-3-line">

<order ng-repeat="order in orders|filter:query|orderBy:activeSorting.directionSign+activeSorting.name"
           order="order" order-click="selectOrder(order)"></order>
```

Comment: Should that be $scope.currentOrder=order;

Comment: @Developer Yeees thanks this have worked, i am a blind idiot

Comment: lol, happens to everyone. Sometimes all you need is extra pair of eyes to fix issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
$attrs.currentOrder=order;
```

to:

```
$scope.currentOrder=order;
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because ng-repeat creates a new scope for each element in orders property.

> The ngRepeat directive instantiates a template once per item from a
>   collection. Each template instance gets its own scope, where the given
>   loop variable is set to the current collection item, and $index is set
>   to the item index or key.